# Keyboard not working on Surface Pro 7

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, microsoft-surface, wireless-keyboard, microsoft-surface-pro

I got a Surface Pro 7 and my keyboard is not working properly.
In fact, in the past, the keyboard was working when it was not magnetized to the screen itself. Now, I'm forced to magnetized/stuck it with the screen/tablet.

Before the keyboard was working in [this position](https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RWFN57?ver=188f&q=90&m=6&h=195&w=348&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&o=t&aim=true). Now, I'm forced to put it in [this position](https://cdn-dynmedia-1.microsoft.com/is/image/microsoftcorp/Surface-Pro-7-Priority_Feature-Comfortable-Feature:VP1-539x349).

You can find here some details about my setup:

- Surface Pro 7
- Windows 11 Family
- Surface Pro Type Cover keyboard (sold with the Surface Pro 7)

Moreover, I know that before a 'Tablet mode' was available but now I can't find it in the settings.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you [edit] the post and specify what keyboard you have?

Answer (score 0):

> I got a Surface Pro 7 and my keyboard is not working properly. In fact, in the past, the keyboard was working when it was not magnetized to the screen itself. Now, I'm forced to magnetized/stuck it with the screen/tablet.

What you describe is impossible since the only way the Surface Pro Type Cover can function is through the magnetic connection.

> Moreover, I know that before a 'Tablet mode' was available but now I can't find it in the settings.

This is intentional.  Tablet Mode was removed with the release of Windows 11.  "Tablet Mode" feature are automatically enabled when the keyboard is disconnected.  You also likely simply have Rotation Lock enabled. **Essentially, just disconnecting the keyboard, enables "Tablet Mode" in Windows 11.**

You can disable `Rotation lock` option within `System -> Display`.

Comment: I made an educated assumption that the magnetic keyboard the author describes is the [Surface Pro Type Cover](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/d/surface-pro-type-cover/91v4vtmhxwpm?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) since that was sold with the Surface Pro 7.

Comment: Before the keyboard was working in [this position](https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RWFN57?ver=188f&q=90&m=6&h=195&w=348&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&o=t&aim=true). Now, I'm forced to put it in [this position](https://cdn-dynmedia-1.microsoft.com/is/image/microsoftcorp/Surface-Pro-7-Priority_Feature-Comfortable-Feature:VP1-539x349). I tried to disable `Rotation lock` but the keyboard is still not working in the first position.

Comment: In both of those images the keyboard is connected to the magnetic connector.  Rotation lock would only come into effect when the, keyboard is disconnected, and you physically rotate the orientation of the tablet.

Comment: Yes now when the keyboard is not folded against the screen it does not work anymore.